# is there a way to get self-or-descendant in an xpath expression without using the [not(self::sub-element)] proprety

Tags: java, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to deal with xml files to get the NodeList in a special xpath expression but also the Nodes in its sub-elements(all childrens) in all levels. we can have several depths in all provided xml files.
I used an xpath like :

```
.//level1/*[preceding-sibling::TITLE[text()='INFORMATION']]/descendant-or-self::*
```

issue with that is I also get redundancy at the end with just the Node of some sub-elements(descendants).

I tried to use the [not(self::sub-element)] property like :

```
.//level1/*[preceding-sibling::TITLE[text()='INFORMATION']]/descendant-or-self::*[[not(self::sub-element2 or self::sub-element2)]
```

but the issue is that i dont have the list of all this redundancy sub-element to include them in the property, so I'm looking for another way to delete this in the returned NodeList.

Taking for exemple the following element :

```
<level1>
     <TITLE>INFORMATION</TITLE>
     <level11>
        <level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A01</level12>: contains <VEAM>NORD and SUD</VEAM> Vendor (V) <SBR>21</SBR> for terms.</level11>
     <level11>
        <level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A02</level12>: No provided.</level11>
     <Empty></Empty>
</level1>
```

I got the following NodeList :

```
<level11> <level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A01</level12>: contains <VEAM>NORD and SUD</VEAM> Vendor (V) <SBR>21</SBR> for terms.</level11>
<level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A01</level12>
<VEAM>NORD and SUD</VEAM>
<SBR>21</SBR>
<level11> <level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A02</level12>: No provided.</level11>
<level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A02</level12>
<Empty/>
```

But i need to got only nodes with all the nodes children and its text without getting cildren nodes alones. there is also other exemples with greater depth.

```
    <level11> <level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A01</level12>: contains <VEAM>NORD and SUD</VEAM> Vendor (V)<SBR>21</SBR>for terms.</level11> 
    <level11> <level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A02</level12>: No provided.</level11>
    <Empty/>
```

**MINDER : without using the [not(self::sub-element)] property**

Comment: Wouldn't e.g. `Level1/TITLE[. = 'INFORMATION']/following-sibling::*` give you the three elements you show as the wanted result?

Comment: following-sibling::*  selects the next chapter sibling of the context node, it's not the requested result

Comment: I had misspelled the first element's name but `level1/TITLE[. = 'INFORMATION']/following-sibling::*` would select the `level11` elements and the `Empty` elements.

Comment: yes but just the second level11 element and not the first and the second together

Comment: In your "exemple" [sic] both `level11` are sibling elements following the `TITLE` elements so of course, in terms of XPath, the expression `level1/TITLE[. = 'INFORMATION']/following-sibling::*` selects both `level11` elements.

Comment: using just descendant:: we will get only the content of children nodes only not concatanated to the node itself content

Answer (score 0):

This XPath gets nodes as requested and per the provided sample

`//level1[./TITLE[text()='INFORMATION']]/*[not(name()='TITLE')]`

Result:

```
<level11>
        <level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A01</level12>: contains <VEAM>NORD and SUD</VEAM> Vendor (V) <SBR>21</SBR> for terms.</level11>
<level11>
        <level12 NAME="A" TYPE="Z">A02</level12>: No provided.</level11>
<Empty/>
```